# "C'est celui que vous" or "C'est celui qui vous"?

Tags: grammaire

I wonder if `que` or `qui` should be used in the sentence

```
C'est celui <..> vous...
```

Because I found it more fit if I use `qui`, which means `who`

```
It's the one <who> you...
```

In this case, he says

```
C'est celui que vous préférez utiliser
```

Which means

```
It's the one who you prefer to use
```

So in this case `que = who` ?

https://youtu.be/8iXi3y1B4Us?t=65

Comment: No, *que* = *whom* in that sentence. If you speak English with perfect 19th century grammar; it really should be *the one whom you prefer to use.* It's just that *whom* has fallen out of use in English over the last 100 years or so. (So the people who explain *que* by saying *que = whom* are confusing people who speak 21st century English.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cf.

- C'est celui que vous avez vu partir. → That’s the one you saw leave. (object)
- C'est celui qui est parti. → That’s the one who left. (subject)

Comment: So `qui` is followed by a verb and in this case, it's `parti`? And `que` is followed by a noun, and in this case it's `vous`?